# Issue populating textarea with db data

Tags: php, html

So, like the title said, i'm having an issue while i'm populating a text area that is being used on HTML form, because it is not getting any content in it.

this is the form with the php while.

```
<?php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{ echo '

    <form action="insert/insertReport.php" id="newReport" method="post">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="clientRep">Cliente</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="client" class="form-control" id="client" value="'.$row['client'].'">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="titleRep">Título do Relatório</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" id="title" value="'.$row['title'].'">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="namefat">Data</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="date" class="form-control" id="date" value="'.$row['date'].'">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="localRep">Local</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="local" class="form-control" id="local" value="'.$row['local'].'">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="reportRep">Relatório</label>
        <br>
        <textarea rows="12" name="report" class="form-control" id="report" form="newReport" value="'.$row['report'].'"></textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" class="form-control" id="id" value="'.$row['id'].'">';

}?>
```

And this is the php query.

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM reports'
```

Does anyone know what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text area does not accept a value attribute. You place the contents between the `textarea` tags:

```
<textarea rows="12" name="report" class="form-control" id="report" form="newReport">'.$row['report'].'</textarea>
```